# get the number of overlapping intervals, given two lists of intervals

Tags: c++, algorithm

I recently came across an interesting problem:

Given two lists of intervals, find the total number of overlapping intervals from the two lists.

```
Example

L1: ([1,2][2,3][4,5][6,7])
L2: ([1,5][2,3][4,7][5,7])

[1,5] overlaps [1,2] [2,3] [4,5]
[2,3] overlaps [1,2] [2,3]
[4,7] overlaps [4,5] [6,7]
[5,7] overlaps [4,5] [6,7]

total = 3+2+2+2 = 9
```

Obviously the brute force approach works, but it's too slow (I need something better than O(n^2)).

I also fond a similar problem [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-number-platforms-required-railwaybus-station/). But it's not exactly the same...

Any help is appreciated

Comment: In this case, I don't think you can get lower than `O(n²)`, because you want the total, so you actually use the information from all combinations, of which there are `n²`. If there are a lot of duplicates in the list, or maybe some other pattern that can be exploited, then maybe you can significantly reduce one or two of the `n`'s, but that's about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make two sorted lists with pairs `(value; +1 or -1 for start and end of interval)`.

Two counters - `Count1` and `Count2` which show number of active intervals in the first and the second lists.

Walk through both lists in merge manner.

When you get pair from the first list with +1 - increment `Count1`

When you get pair from the first list with -1 - decrement `Count1` and add `Count2` to the result

The same for pairs from the second list

Pseudocode for the last stage

```
CntA = 0
CntB = 0
Res = 0
ia = 0
ib = 0
while (ia < A.Length) and (ib < B.Length)
    if Compare(A[ia], B[ib]) <= 0
          CntA = CntA + A[ia].Flag
          if (A[ia].Flag < 0)
               Res = Res + CntB
          ia++
    else
          CntB = CntB + B[ib].Flag
          if B[ib].Flag < 0
             Res = Res + CntA
          ib++
```

Subtle moment - comparison `if Compare(A[ia], B[ib]) <= 0`
We should here take into account also flags  - to correctly treat situations when endpoints only touch like [1..2][2..3] (you consider this situation as intersection). So both sorting and merge comparator should take synthetic value  like this: `3 * A[ia].Value - A[ia].Flag`. With such comparing start of interval is treated before end of interval with the same coordinate.

P.S. Made quick test in Delphi. Works for given data set and pair of others.

[Delphi code](http://ideone.com/aDC3Uh) (ideone FPC doesn't compile it due to generics)

Comment: Sorry I'm not following; you have two lists, each one containing intervals. How do you get from that to two sorted lists of pair<value,+/-1> ??  If you are merging the two lists then you are not solving the problem because you are also counting the number of overlapping intervals in each list with themselves.

Comment: You don't merge lists really. At every step you choose a pair with the next coordinate from both lists. I'll try to make an example or pseudocode

Comment: the code almost works : with the synthetic value it return the wrong value; with it it return 9 but fails other test cases where the edges on the interval overlap (an interval starts where the other ends)

Comment: using normal comparison: provided test case return 9 ;([1 2][2 3]) ([2 2][2 3]) return 3 (instead of 4). using synthetic value for comparison: base case returns 10; ([1 2][2 3]) ([2 2][2 3]) returns 4

Comment: OK, will check later.

Comment: With synthetic value my code gives 9 for you first set, 4 for `([1 2][2 3]) ([2 2][2 3])`

Comment: Ok, I was using wrong synthetic value 2x instead of 3x..I can see why the first one won't work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am quite late. Would you mind elaborating your sorting method? And why are you using an artificial coefficient 3? Many Thanks

Comment: I've used inbuilt sorting method. Only comparator function is important. Coefficient 3 has been chosen to provide priority to value rather than flag (value 5 with any flag is 'larger' than value 4 with any flag, but value 5 with flag -1 is 'larger' than  value 5 with flag +1)

Comment: Thank you for your  reply! I think I didn't formulate my question well. I am sorry I am not familiar with Delphi, so I couldn't figure out your comparator function. It seems to me, for example, given `([1 2][2 3]) ([2 2][2 3])`, they are sorted as `([1,1], [2,1], [2,-1], [3,-1])` with weight `(2, 5, 7, 10) `and '([1,1], [2,1],[3,-1],[5,-1])`  with weight` (2, 5,  10, 16)`. Did I follow you correctly so far? Thanks a lot.

Comment: First list looks right, for the second I see some contradictions - where are 1 and 5 values from?

Comment: Sorry, I was working on the `([1 5][2 3])` as part of the original problem.  Given `([1 2][2 3]) (1,5][2 3])`,  the two sorted lists are `([1,1], [2,1], [2,-1], [3,-1])` with weight `(2, 5, 7, 10)`, and  `([1,1], [2,1],[3,-1],[5,-1])` with weight `(2, 5, 10, 16)`.

Comment: I am really sorry, could I ask some more questions? Do you mind if we use chat (as stack is suggesting now).

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure that will have time for live discussion. You can create chat, but if I don't answer in a long time, write question here too.

Comment: No problem, I'll just write questions here. So basically I guess what we are trying to track if a starting point is less than starting points from the other lane (then it is a candidate for overlapping interval)? But I don't totally understand how it is realized with your counters. Would you mind explaining it a bit?

Comment: Try to draw intervals on the paper and understand concept of active ones (those opened in current position) . Mote three active intervals from the second list at 4..5 segment. So interval from the first list that ends at this segment, intersect with 3 three intervals from the second list

Comment: For example, I am very puzzled by the fact that once we have a `-1` then we add counter for another lane to the global result? Also I though we'd need to reset the counter once it's been add to the global result?

Comment: Thank you! when you say there are "three active intervals from the second list at 4..5 segment"? Did you meant OP's original problem?

Comment: So does counterA represent the active intervals from the first list at that moment?

Comment: Yes, and code `CntA = CntA + A[ia].Flag` provides this property

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try to think the rest over. Again, thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry again. I am wondering if the problem asks to find the actual pair of overlapping intervals, what can we do?

Comment: Store interval number in structure with end value and flag. I think you are solving another problem...

Comment: With the interval number I can know some of them, ones that ceases to be active. But I don't know which are it's active pairs from the other lane then. Yes I am thinking a variant of op. Do you think I am better off starting a new question?

Comment: I forgot mention if we use hash table then we can record active intervals. I am think if hash table is a must.

Answer (score 3):

Try to look for sweep line algorithms, it will give you the fastest solution.

You can check short description at [TopCoder site](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/line-sweep-algorithms/) or watch [video from Robert Sedgwick](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dePDHVovJlE). These describe a bit more hard problem but should give you an approach how to solve yours.

Actually the main idea is to walk over sorted list of begins and ends of your segments each time updating the lists of segments in the special intersecting list.

For this task you will have two intersections lists for each original list respectively. At the start both intersection lists are empty. On coming over begin of the segment you add it to the appropriate intersection list and it obviously intersects all the segments in the other intersection list. When coming to an end of the segment just remove it from the intersection list.

This algorithm will give you O(n log(n)) speed and in worst case O(n) memory.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use std::set_intersection in a loop over the second array to match it with each item in the first array. But I am not sure if the performance will match your requirements.

Comment: that is just the brute force approach using library functions.

Answer (score 0):

I recently stumbled upon the [Interval Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) ADT when tackling a similar question - I suspect it'll be useful for you, whether you implement it or not.

It is basically a ternary tree, and I built it with nodes containing:

- Left sub-tree containing intervals less than current node
- Right sub-tree containing intervals more than current node
- List of overlapping intervals
- Interval value encompassing all overlapping intervals

After building the tree in `O(n*log(n))`, a query function - to check overlapping intervals - should be `O(log(n) + m)` where `m` is the number of overlapping intervals reported.

*Note* that on creation, sorting by end value in the interval and splitting the list should help keep things balanced.

Comment: interval trees or segment trees are useful for situations where you have to perform multiple queries on the same input data. Not the case here. I am 90% sure that solution will time out.

Comment: True, maybe it'll time out if this is purely a question around competitive programming, but I'm happy I spent the time looking into the ADT, and thought it was worth sharing....